# XE8 project not able to find iOS Provision Profile since XCode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

I've just updated XCode to version 7.3 for iOS 9.3 SDK. But since this update my Delphi XE8 isn't able to find the Provision Profile. Now i'm not able to build or deploy for iOS with XE8. First thought it was a connection problem but testen the connection and works fine!

*In Delphi 10 it works fine. There it can find the profile and build.*

**Anyone knows a fix for this?**

Comment: I've a similar issue, which I constantly see "Please specify exact device present UUID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning my Keys on my Mac and restarting everything my problem was solved